# Facebook: Post to friend's wall but NOT to their feed (Graph API)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using the graph API to post to the the wall of a friend.
However I do not want the post to be visible on any News Feeds
(the posting user, the friend being posted to, or anyone else).

How can I achieve this. Here is my wall post code:

```
function fb_post($to_uid,$acToken) {
    $result = false;
    global $fb;
    $feed_dir = '/'.$to_uid.'/feed/'; 
    $message_str =  'This is a message';
    $msg_body = array('access_token' => $acToken, 
                      'message' => $message_str, 
                      'name' => 'Wall Post',
                      'caption' => "I posted to your wall",
                      'link' => 'http://www.wallpost.com',
                      'description' => 'Learn how to post to peoples walls', 
                      'picture' => 'http://image.com/myimage.jpg',
                      'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Wall Post',
                                  'link' => 'http://www.wallpost.com'))
                      );

    try {
        $result = $fb->api($feed_dir, 'post', $msg_body);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {       
              echo "Not sent";
       }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to post something that will not be visible to anyone? This is the same effect as not posting anything at all. The latter being easier to do.

Comment: A user's wall and a user's News Feed are two different things. One can be seen by clicking 'Profile' (your wall) and the other can be seen by clicking 'Home' (your news feed). I want to post to wall but not see it on news feed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Facebook's `recent` lists and so on are a dynamic amalgamation of posts - a post can't be marked to opt-out of this, Facebook decides its relevancy and coverage.

A user may have their profile configured to so that postings of certain types/from certain applications are handled in a specific way, but there's nothing you can personally do about that - and I still don't think it encompasses options to `hide` posts from feeds, mainly just disallow them from their wall in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'privacy' => '{value: SELF}'. However, it work for users who are already in application. So friend of user who posting something to his friend's wall should be authorized in our application as well